# How do I read a matrix from a file into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

Hey guys Im trying to be able to save an array from a text file but I'm at my wits end trying to figure out how to save it. I can print all the elements of the matrix as can be seen from the text file.

Sample input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6 
3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I keep getting an index out of range exception. Not sure what's happening.
Hopefully you guys understand what im trying to do.
Here's what I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input =
            @"C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 15\Chapter 15 Question 5\Chapter 15 Question 5\TextFile1.txt";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        char[] unwanted = new char[] { ' ' };
        using (reader)
        {
            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                string[] numbersString = line.Split(unwanted);
                int[,] numbersInt = new int [ row, numbersString.Length];
                foreach (string a in numbersString)
                {

                    Console.Write("{0} ",a);// this is to check that the array was read in the right order
                    numbersInt[row, column] = int.Parse(a);
                    column++;
                }
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code just reads from a file, it's not saving anything...? I.e. you need a `StreamWriter` or something similar to write a file. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 )  However, I don't really understand why you want to read something from a file just to save it again.

Comment: Where is the error thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *jugged* arrays (array of array `int[][]`) instead of *2D* ones; in that case the solution will be quite simple, something like this (*Linq*):

```
int[][] matrix = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\myFile.txt")
  .Split(new Char[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(items => items
     .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
     .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Test (let's print out the matrix):

```
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, matrix
    .Select(line => String.Join(" ", line)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Answer (score 0):

This change in your `while` should do the trick:

```
while (line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/94223t4d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue is that your code does not reset `column` back to zero after reading each line. Move `int column = 0` into the `while` loop to fix this issue.

The second issue is `numbersInt` allocation. You create it for each line, which is not right, because it's a 2-D array. You need to create it before the loop, but of course you can't, because you don't know how many lines you are going to have. One approach is to use a dynamic data structure, and add one row at a time to it.

You can greatly simplify your code by using [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method in combination with LINQ, because this would let you get rid of a lot of simple code. Now you can check how many lines you have before creating your 2-D array, and you could fill it in much easier as well:

```
var allRows = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Nate\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Chapter 15\Chapter 15 Question 5\Chapter 15 Question 5\TextFile1.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(unwanted).Select(int.Parse).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

If you are OK with an array of arrays, you don't need to do anything: `allRows` is a 2-D structure of rows and columns containing your matrix.

If you must convert it to a 2-D array, you can do it with a pair of nested `for` loops:

```
if (allRows.Count == 0) {
    // ... The file has no data - handle this error
}
var matrix = new int[allRows.Count, allRows[0].Count];
for (int row = 0 ; row != allRows.Count ; row++) {
    for (int col = 0 ; col != allRows[0].Count ;col++) {
        matrix[row, col] = allRows[row][col];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be creating your instance of numbersInt inside your while loop. This means that with each pass of the loop you will re-create the array and when the loop exits the array will be lost. Move the declaration for numberInt to outside of the while loop.